# SSH: Troubleshooting "Remote port forwarding failed for listen port" errors

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, port-forwarding, port

Question: Why does `ssh -N -R 2222:localhost:22 <bluehost_user>@<bluehost_ip>` result in a "Remote port forwarding failed for listen port" error? The objective is to establish a reverse tunnel with port forwarding in order to consistently ssh into a host behind a NAT router that has a dynamic private IP. See image for details.

**Already Tried:**

1. Researched existing literature on Google, Stackoverflow, etc. There are topics concerning this error message, however the resolutions given resolve root causes different than that of this particular instance because those resolutions do not resolve the error in this case.
2. I've performed several diagnostics to validate the required ports are open. Some of those results are shown in the image below.

**Reverse SSH Tunnel**

[image: Image 1]

**Update**

I was trying the following command for Step 2:
`reduser@redhost:~ ssh greenuser@greenhost -p 2222`

It should be:
`reduser@redhost:~ ssh greenuser@bluehost -p 2222`
You want to use the greenuser credentials on the bluehost IP because the host you are loging into when you use port 2222 is really the greenhost.

Comment: Have you checked out http://serverfault.com/questions/595323/ssh-remote-port-forwarding-failed ?

Comment: @balwa Checked but that is about connections expiring after a period of time. The connection never succeeds in my case. I also make use of the KeepAliveInterval parameters so there is explicit control over some of the time factors.

Comment: @ModeratorImpersonator tried `ssh -N -R <bluehost_ip>:2222:localhost:22` and ssh seemed to take that as invalid syntax. ssh simply returned ```usage: ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
           [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec]
           ...
```

Comment: SSH aside, what if you go to the remote computer and try to run a server on port 2222? e.g. if you have cygwin on there and do `nc -l 2222` or `nc -l -p 2222` (whichever notation the nc with cygwin uses)

Comment: The above command works just fine on my system (just add the **-f** flag, so that you can get a prompt back). You do not seem to have the **-R** flag, are you sure? Are you sure there is nothing already using port 2222?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae he does have -R, look carefully, just before the `2222:...`  and if he didn't have a -R or -L there then the command would get less far than it has.  He just put that -R port:ip:port  near the end of his command line, so perhaps that's why you couldn't see it.

Comment: I know it's not the cause of this specific question, but since googling the message leads here I'd note that using a port < 1024 also results in this same message.

Answer (score 33):

> Why does `ssh -N -R 2222:localhost:22 <bluehost_user>@<bluehost_ip>` result in a "Remote port forwarding failed for listen port" error?

I get this exact warning when I attempt to use a port that is already taken on the remote side.

The output of `netstat` from `bluehost` indicates that something is already listening on port `2222` there. It doesn't show what it is though.

**Solutions:**

1. Change `2222` in your `ssh` invocation to some other port which is not in use on `bluehost`. Just make it greater than `1023` because regular users can't bind to *[well-known ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Well-known_ports)*; otherwise you will get the same warning regardless of whether the port is in use or not.
2. Or identify the listening process (on `bluehost`) with `sudo lsof -i TCP:2222`; terminate or reconfigure it to make the port `2222` available.

---

**Edit:**

In your case this part of `man ssh` seems important:

> ```
> -R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
> -R [bind_address:]port:local_socket
> -R remote_socket:host:hostport
> -R remote_socket:local_socket
> ```
>
> […] By default, TCP listening sockets on the server will be bound to the loopback interface only. This may be overridden by specifying a `bind_address`.  An empty `bind_address`, or the address ‘`*`’, indicates that the remote socket should listen on all interfaces. Specifying a remote `bind_address` will only succeed if the server's `GatewayPorts` option is enabled (see `sshd_config(5)`).

It means you should have `GatewayPorts yes` in the `sshd_config` on `bluehost`. Read `man 5 sshd_config` to learn more. Don't forget to reload the service afterwards.

Comment: Interestingly, I'm seeing a connection from China (note I was using this host as a VPN from China when I was there a few weeks ago). While this host is a sandbox, it's still concerning ```<bluehost_user>@<bluehost_ip>:~$ netstat | grep 2222
tcp        0      0 <bluehost_ip>:2222     htuidc.bgp.ip:2599      SYN_RECV``` Port 2222 open or not, how would one connect without a username and password (note this is tcp not ssh)? I do have sshd listening on 2222 as configured in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

Comment: Additional info from `lsof`: ```COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd    1034 root    3u  IPv4  13344      0t0  TCP *:2222 (LISTEN)
sshd    1034 root    4u  IPv6  13353      0t0  TCP *:2222 (LISTEN)```

Comment: @ngm_code So it's your `sshd` that needs to be reconfigured. Or just use another port when you `ssh -R` from elsewhere.

Comment: Ok, I will take a look. So you're saying it's incompatible to open a port via `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` prior to opening it up at runtime via a call to ssh in the CLI?

Comment: @ngm_code Yes. Ports (or one port, usually `22`) configured in `sshd_config` are for SSH clients to connect to. In your case you connect to one of these ports and order `sshd` to open *additional* port and tunnel it to your machine. If it could be the same port then `sshd` wouldn't know whether incoming packets are destined to it or to the tunnel.

Comment: Solved it! Red host should initiate `ssh <greenhost_user>@<bluehost_ip> -p 2222`. Easy gotcha, you want to use the greenhost username with the bluehost ip.

Comment: @ Googlers: To free up a TCP port, use `fuser -k 2222/tcp` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750604/freeing-up-a-tcp-ip-port/750705#750705))

Answer (score 10):

Make sure there is no hanging connection on port 2222 at bluehost.
Test at bluehost `lsof -t -i:2222` whether any process id is using port 2222. Additionally, kill this process (for example with `kill $(lsof -t -i:2222)`).

This resolved the issue for me. Hopefully this information is useful for someone else. :)

Comment: In my case it was a previous `sshd` process, because I have a loop on the client side restarting the tunnel in case it fails...